# OctopusDeploy not deploying package to Custom Installation Directory

Tags: octopus-deploy, octopus

I'm pretty new to OctopusDeploy and am trying to set up a process to deploy our artifact to multiple Windows Servers.

As of right now it is deploying the package to the default working directory of `C:\Octopus\Applications......` but I need it to be deployed to a different path.

I have defined a Custom Install Directory in the process editor, however this seems to be overlooked during the deployment, and the package just goes to the default directory.

I have tried substituting the path with a variable, but that didn't fix it. There are no errors or warnings in the deployment logs.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're taking the right steps to change your custom installation directory on your deployment.

One thing to check is that you've created a new release since updating your step configuration. Because [releases in Octopus snapshot the deployment process](https://octopus.com/docs/getting-started/best-practices/releases-and-deployments#updating-a-release), any updates you make won't show up in your deployments until you've created a new release.

Comment: Yes that was the answer - thanks